# dereferenced iterator in range based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

In this code:

```
string s = "hello";

for(auto i : s)
{
    i = 'p';
    cout<<i<<'\n';
} 
cout<<s<<endl;
```

the output will be:

```
p
p
p
p
p
hello
```

So when `i` is used to refer to the next element in string `s` it is not an iterator but a dereferenced iterator?
Had it been `auto &i` it would certainly have changed the value of string `s` pointing that it is dereferenced iterator. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  Now, read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts), and preferably avoid using `auto` in general.

Answer (score -1):

> *So when i is used to refer to the next element in string s it is not an iterator but a dereferenced iterator?*

Kind of.
`i` copies the value of the iterator position in `s`. It's not a reference. In most use cases, the `i` value is not expected to be changed, then you may use:

```
for(const auto& i : s)
```

> *Had it been auto &i it would certainly have changed the value of string s pointing that it is dereferenced iterator. Is it correct?*

Yes. `for(auto& i : s)`, makes the `s` modifiable due to `i`.